# What is Jer. 48:11 refering to?

Tags: word-study, jeremiah

What does Jer. 48:11 refer to when it says that his smell/taste remains in him and his scent is not changed? What does the smell/taste and scent refer to?

Answer (score 1):

in Jer 48:11, the prophet uses the metaphor of wine to describe Moabs unchanged moral state:

> Moab has been at rest from youth, like wine left on its dregs, not
> poured from one jar to another— she has not gone into exile. So she
> tastes as she did, and her aroma is unchanged.

Ellicott correctly observes:

> The image, found also in Zephaniah 1:12, is drawn from the practice of
> pouring wine from one vessel into another to clarify it and improve
> its flavour. Wine not so treated retained its first crude bitterness.
> So, the prophet says, it is with nations. It is not good for them to
> remain too long in a prosperity which does but strengthen their
> natural arrogance. There is a wholesome discipline in defeat, even in
> exile. In Jeremiah 48:47 we have the hope of the prophet that the
> discipline will do its work. The “vessels” and “bottles” of Jeremiah
> 48:12 are, of course, the cities and villages of Moab. (Comp. the
> imagery of Jeremiah 19:10.)

While Barnes is slightly different the point remains the same - Moab is the same as before.  Matthew Poole is far more succinct:

> **He hath settled on his lees**; like to a cask of wine, that hath not been racked, but hath continued in the same state.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremiah 48:11 (NIV)

> “Moab has been at rest from youth,
> like wine left on its dregs,
> not poured from one jar to another—
> she has not gone into exile.
> So she tastes as she did,
> and her aroma is unchanged.

Wine represents the Moabites, dregs represents their god Chemosh. As wine has long been at rest, the dregs is settle at the bottom. The taste of wine comes from its dregs, a metaphor that the sins of the Moabites originated from their god Chemosh. The aroma (scent) of the wine, a metaphor the love and attachment of Moabites to their god Chemosh. To end the sins of the Moabites, in the next verse Jeremiah 48:12 (NIV), God said:

> But days are coming,”
> declares the Lord,
> “when I will send men who pour from pitchers,
> and they will pour her out;
> they will empty her pitchers
> and smash her jars.

So God will send men who pour from pitchers, and they will pour her out, a metaphor that the Moabites will be exiled. When wine is empty, the dregs left behind, then God will smash her jars, where the dregs no longer sit, a metaphor Chemosh will be exterminated.